# dxn:NavBarGroup IsExpandable control in wpf xaml code

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I would like to set NavBarGroup IsExpanded property using button trigger in XAML without writing code behind. I wrote some backed code which is like in my attachment.  When I click a button one navbargroup is collapsing and another navbargroup is expanding I am trying to do this just using xaml code. Can you give me an example for doing this?
So I am also not sure if this is the most efficient way of setting the IsExpanded value, if you have better solution please mention me.

my xaml code following as below

```
                                                    <Button x:Name="btnCaseSearch"
                                                            Command="{Binding DataContext.AdvancedSearchCaseCommand}"
                                                            Template="{StaticResource btnGenericAqua}"
                                                            Foreground="#FF262A2F"
                                                            Grid.Row="7"
                                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                                            Height="44"
                                                            Content="ARA"
                                                            FontWeight="Bold"
                                                            Click="btnSearch_Click">
                                                    </Button>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </dxn:ExplorerBarView.ItemTemplate>

                                    </dxn:ExplorerBarView>
                                </dxn:NavBarControl.View>



                                <dxn:NavBarControl.Groups>
                                    <dxn:NavBarGroup Header="CaseSearchGroup"
                                                     x:Name="CaseSearchNavBar"
                                                     IsExpanded="False">
                                        <dxn:NavBarItem></dxn:NavBarItem>
                                    </dxn:NavBarGroup>

                                </dxn:NavBarControl.Groups>
```

my ViewModel side code following as below

```
  private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (((Button)sender).Name)
        {
            case "btnCaseSearch":
                CaseSearchNavBar.IsExpanded = false;
                CaseSearchResultNavBar.IsExpanded = true;
                break;

            case "btnLevySearch":
                LevySearchNavBar.IsExpanded = false;
                LevySearchResultNavBar.IsExpanded = true;
                break;
            case "btnDunningLetterSearch":
                DunningLetterSearchNavBar.IsExpanded = false;
                DunningLetterSearchResultNavBar.IsExpanded = true;
                break;
            case "btnPowerOfAttorneySearch":
                PowerOfAttorneySearchNavBar.IsExpanded = false;
                PowerOfAttorneySearchResultNavBar.IsExpanded = true;
                break;
            case "btnContractSearch":
                ContractSearchNavBar.IsExpanded = false;
                ContractSearchResultNavBar.IsExpanded = true;
                break;
            case "btnDesignSearch":
                DesignSearchNavBar.IsExpanded = false;
                DesignSearchResultNavBar.IsExpanded = true;
                break;
            case "btnPatentSearch":
                PatentSearchNavBar.IsExpanded = false;
                PatentSearchResultNavBar.IsExpanded = true;
                break;
            case "btnBrandSearch":
                BrandSearchNavBar.IsExpanded = false;
                BrandSearchResultNavBar.IsExpanded = true;
                break;
            case "btnLicenseSearch":
                LicenseSearchNavBar.IsExpanded = false;
                LicenseSearchResultNavBar.IsExpanded = true;
                break;
            case "btnCommercialRegisterSearch":
                CommercialRegisterSearchNavBar.IsExpanded = false;
                CommercialRegisterSearchResultNavBar.IsExpanded = true;
                break;
            case "btnWarrantyLetterSearch":
                WarrantyLetterSearchNavBar.IsExpanded = false;
                WarrantyLetterSearchResultNavBar.IsExpanded = true;
                break;
            case "btnMeetingSearch":
                MeetingSearchNavBar.IsExpanded = false;
                MeetingSearchResultNavBar.IsExpanded = true;
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could use a `ToggleButton` instead? You can then bind your `IsExpanded` property to the `IsChecked` property of the `ToggleButton`.

Comment: yes it is looks useful but I am quite newbie to wpf so I don't know how can i use in my structure toggle button.